# Ruby on rails - Model, validation coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, coordinates

here is my question.
I have a map and I want the user can create a marker only into a certain area. In javascript all is done well BUT I want a validation also in Ruby on Rails, on the model. How can I proceed? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you need a general guidance in validating models in Rails, or you want some help in validating the coordinates? If the second one is the problem, you could show some code, or in any way describe your problem with more details. If you prefer reading instead of watching movies, you may find this guide useful: (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Comment: I want to build validations on the "coordinates" attribute of my model, so that can be accepted only coordinates into a certain area.

Comment: How is your 'area' defined? What is the value of the 'coordinates' attribute? You definitely should show some code. What have you tried and what did not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [model validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3), which are of great help. Also [described here](http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3).